# Custom Error Message Page

Tags: php, html

I'm really new to this. I got this code online for a message form.

html

```
<form name="htmlform" method="post" action="html_form_send.php">
<table width="50%px" align="center">
<tr>
 <td valign="top" align="center">
  <input  type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td align="center" valign="top">
  <label for="first_name"><h5>*First Name</h5></label>
 </td>
 </tr>


 <tr>
 <td valign="top" align="center">
  <input  type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top" align="center">
  <label for="last_name"><h5>*Last Name</h5></label>
 </td>
 </tr>


 <tr>
 <td valign="top" align="center">
  <input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30">
 </td>
 <tr>
 <td valign="top" align="center">
  <label for="email"><h5>*Email Address</h5></label>
 </td>
 </tr>


 <tr>
 <td valign="top" align="center">
  <input  type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top" align="center">
  <label for="telephone"><h5>Telephone Number</h5></label>
 </td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td valign="top" align="center">
  <textarea  name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="32" rows="4"></textarea>
 </td>
 <tr>
 <td valign="top" align="center">
  <label for="comments"><h5>*Message</h5></label>
 </td>
 </tr>

</tr>
<tr>
 <td height="106" colspan="2" valign="top" style="text-align:center">
  <input type="image" src="images/send.png" width="90px">
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // CHANGE THE TWO LINES BELOW
    $email_to = "yourname@yourdomain.com";

    $email_subject = "Contact Form";


    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }

    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>

<!-- place your own success html below -->




<?php
}
die();
?>
```

I took out some things to save room, like my html for the success page.

I cannot load pictures until I get a reputation built up. But, my success page is the same as my other pages. Has the same header, footer, backgrounds, etc. but my error page is just a blank white page with only test.

How can I make the error page look just like the success page with just different text?

Comment: I think you misunderstood. I'm not getting any errors. Whenever you type in an invalid email, or leave the name, or message boxes blank, it shows an error to the person who is trying to send me the message. I want the error page they see to match the rest of my site.

Comment: Yup, thought you were saying you were getting a blank screen. So there are a few ways to accomplish that. 1. validate the form on the same page you submit it on. 2. redirect (with `header(`) the user back to the same page with the status of the submission and change the display of the page based on that response, after this processing (e.g. don't output anything here store it all to variable and send back)